# c++11 decltype returns reference type

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I am a little bit confused about why `decltype` with the comma operator returns reference type in some cases.

for example, in this code:

```
int i = 101;
decltype(1, i) var = i;
var = 20;
printf("%d\n", i); // will print 20
```

here, var is int& instead of int, but if I replace the second line with:

```
decltype(i) var = i;
```

it will return int!

can anyone please explain that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`decltype` is special-cased for an unparenthesized *id-expression* to give the type of the entity, without reference qualification **[dcl.type.simple]**:

> 4 - The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>   — if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. [...]
>   — otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`; [...]

By providing a comma expression you are disabling this special case, as with parentheses:

```
decltype(i)    // int
decltype((i))  // int&
decltype(1, i) // int&
```

`(i)` and `1, i` are lvalue expressions, so their `decltype` is a reference type.

Comment: Why is 1,i an lvalue?

Comment: @Greycon `1,i` returns an `lvalue` reference of the last operand left to right.

Comment: @Greycon comma expressions have the type and value category of their RHS operand. "*The type
and value of the result are the type and value of the right operand; the result is of the same value category
as its right operand* [...]"

Comment: OK, thanks. So, the type of 1,i is the type of i, which is int? If so, surely the MSVC Compiler correctly prints 101 from the OP. That is decltype(1,i) yields int, not int &   - Am I correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just re-read your extract from the standard, I get it now. Thanks for the education :-)

Comment: To see why `(1,i)` is an lvalue, examine `(1,i) = 7`, which assigns `7` to `i`.